# How to Redirect to new asp page while clicking on the data row of the data grid view in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My data grid view in asp.net displays only selected id from sql server database as a single row.

Now I need to display a particular page when I click on the particular id (data row) and also I want to display all the details in a new page belongs to the selected id (on click on the id).

I have tried this code:

```
protected void btnserch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection objsqlconnection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING);
    string query = "Select id from registration";
    SqlCommand objsqlcommand = new SqlCommand(query, objsqlconnection);
    objsqlconnection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    objsqlcommand.CommandText = query; 
    objsqlcommand.Connection = objsqlconnection;  
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(objsqlcommand);  
    da.Fill(ds);  
    objsqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    GridView1.DataSource = ds; 
    GridView1.DataBind();
    objsqlconnection.Close();
}
```

This code returns a grid by selecting only id column from registration table. Now when I click on the data row of the id column, I need an another page which should display all the  details belonging to that id.

Comment: OnItemDataBound is your friend here.

Comment: Have a template field with the link (with `Eval("Id")`)

Answer (score 0):

like @MelanciaUK said "OnItemDataBound" is your friend.
For checking ID even on postback, select it in "SelectedIndexChanging"

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to redirect to new page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" autogeneratedcolumn="false">
<asp:TemplateField HaderText="ID">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("ID")%>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HaderText="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("ID")%>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HaderText="Edit">
<ItemTemplate>
<a href='Newpage.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID")%>'>Edit</a> 
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
<asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect from one page another page in two ways

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" autogeneratedcolumn="false"> 
   <asp:TemplateField HaderText="Action">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <a href='mypage.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("RowID")%>'>Edit</a> 
     <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="Redirect(<%#Eval("RowID")%>);">Edit</a> 

   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TemplateField>
<asp:GridView> 


<script type="text/javascript">

function Redirect(id) {
    window.location = 'mypage.aspx?ID=' + id;
}
</script>
```